# unclosed quote mark after the character string java

Tags: java

i am reading 3 pakets like mail to mail subject and mail message bu but when i am inserting data into database i got this error here is a somne part of code

```
aSocket.receive(to);
String towards=new String(to.getData());
System.out.println(towards);
aSocket.receive(sub);
String subject=new String(sub.getData());
aSocket.receive(msg);
String message=new String(msg.getData());
sendedmail(towards,subject,message,username);

public void sendedmail(String to,String sub,String msg,String from){
    try{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
    }
    try{
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:udp");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        int status=0;
        String query;
        query = "INSERT INTO emails(emailto, emailfrom, message, userstatus, subject) VALUES('"+to+"','"+from+"','"+msg+"','"+status+"','"+sub+"')";
        int f=st.executeUpdate(query); 
        if(f==1){
            System.out.println("row inserted");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("row not inserted");
        }  
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Instead of createStatement, whu don't you use preparedStatement? Thus single quote issue could be avoided.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: And you shouldn't use the JDBC/ODBC bridge. It has always been buggy and slow and is no longer supported in Java8. Use a real JDBC driver instead.

Comment: ok let me check... thanks to reply :)

Comment: which is driver is better?? –  a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @tousifahmed Try [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/) preparedStatement example

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, quotes are escaped by doubling them, eg:

```
insert ... values ('O''Brien');
```

So you need to replace all quotes with doubled quotes:

```
 str = str.replace("'", "''");
```

---

Oh, and it's been about 15 years since you needed to load the JDBC driver class before using it; just delete the whole first try-catch.